# How use the i18n in ng2-table component?

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I try use the [ng2-table](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table), but i need translate the header and the placeholder, i use the [ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/releases) to translate.

I need translate each colum, but if i use the translation.instant("my.text") i receive only the key. I am studying the angular and i not know how solve this.

if i use in html the translation work, {{ "my.text" | translate }}, but i don't know how use with ng2-table.

This is my component.html

```
<div class="content-heading">
    <div>Data-Tables components
        <small>Native and not wrapped angular2 based data-tables</small></div>
</div>
<!-- <alert [type]="'info'">None of this examples are based on the official jQuery-Datatables</alert> -->
<h4 class="page-header">ng2 Table
    <small>Simple table extension with sorting, filtering, paging... for Angular2 apps by ValorSoftware</small>
</h4>
<div class="mb-3 clearfix">
    <div class="pull-let wd-md">
        <input *ngIf="config.filtering" placeholder="Filter all columns" [ngTableFiltering]="config.filtering" class="form-control" (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card card-default">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <ng-table [config]="config" (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)" (cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns"></ng-table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-right">
    <pagination *ngIf="config.paging" class="pagination-sm" [(ngModel)]="page" [totalItems]="length" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage" [maxSize]="maxSize" [boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="onChangeTable(config, $event)" (numPages)="numPages = $event">
    </pagination>
</div>
<!-- <pre *ngIf="config.paging" class="card card-block card-header">Page: {{page}} / {{numPages}}</pre> -->
```

This is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { TableData } from './ng2-table-data';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-datatable',
    templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.scss']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

    public singleData;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        // ng2Table
        this.length = this.ng2TableData.length;
    }

    // ng2Table
    public rows: Array<any> = [];
    public columns: Array<any> = [
        { title: 'Name', name: 'name', filtering: { filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by name' } },
        {
            title: 'Position',
            name: 'position',
            sort: false,
            filtering: { filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by position' }
        },
        { title: 'Office', className: ['office-header', 'text-success'], name: 'office', sort: 'asc' },
        { title: 'Extn.', name: 'ext', sort: '', filtering: { filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by extn.' } },
        { title: 'Start date', className: 'text-warning', name: 'startDate' },
        { title: 'Salary ($)', name: 'salary' }
    ];
    public page: number = 1;
    public itemsPerPage: number = 10;
    public maxSize: number = 5;
    public numPages: number = 1;
    public length: number = 0;

    public config: any = {
        paging: true,
        sorting: { columns: this.columns },
        filtering: { filterString: '' },
        className: ['table-striped', 'table-bordered', 'mb-0', 'd-table-fixed']
    };

    public ng2TableData: Array<any> = TableData;

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onChangeTable(this.config);
    }

    public changePage(page: any, data: Array<any> = this.ng2TableData): Array<any> {
        let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
        let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : data.length;
        return data.slice(start, end);
    }

    public changeSort(data: any, config: any): any {
        if (!config.sorting) {
            return data;
        }

        let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
        let columnName: string = void 0;
        let sort: string = void 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (columns[i].sort !== '' && columns[i].sort !== false) {
                columnName = columns[i].name;
                sort = columns[i].sort;
            }
        }

        if (!columnName) {
            return data;
        }

        // simple sorting
        return data.sort((previous: any, current: any) => {
            if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
                return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
                return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }

    public changeFilter(data: any, config: any): any {

        let filteredData: Array<any> = data;
        this.columns.forEach((column: any) => {
            if (column.filtering) {
                filteredData = filteredData.filter((item: any) => {
                    return item[column.name].match(column.filtering.filterString);
                });
            }
        });

        if (!config.filtering) {
            return filteredData;
        }

        if (config.filtering.columnName) {
            return filteredData.filter((item: any) =>
                item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));
        }

        let tempArray: Array<any> = [];
        filteredData.forEach((item: any) => {
            let flag = false;
            this.columns.forEach((column: any) => {
                if (item[column.name].toString().match(this.config.filtering.filterString)) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            });
            if (flag) {
                tempArray.push(item);
            }
        });
        filteredData = tempArray;

        return filteredData;
    }

    public onChangeTable(config: any, page: any = { page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage }): any {
        if (config.filtering) {
            (<any>Object).assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
        }

        if (config.sorting) {
            (<any>Object).assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
        }

        let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.ng2TableData, this.config);
        let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
        this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
        this.length = sortedData.length;
    }

    public onCellClick(data: any): any {
        console.log(data);
    }

}
```